# Path with json extension not handled by custom handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, httphandler, global-asax

I'm trying to add custom handler- DayOfWeekHandler([Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 Platform Book](http://www.apress.com/9781430265412) is referred for setup).

Route in routes.config:

```
routes.Add(new Route("handler/path", new CustomHandler() 
{ HandlerType = typeof(DayOfWeekHandler) }));
```

Custom Handler:

```
public class CustomHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public Type HandlerType;
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return (IHttpHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(HandlerType);
    }
}
```

when I enter "http://localhost:81/handler/path" in the browser - It is correctly calling `ProcessRequest` method from handler, however when I enter "http://localhost:81/handler/path.json", I'm getting 404.0 error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. In this case it is not even calling Process Request method.
```

ProcessRequest method in DayOfWeekHandler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
            string day = DateTime.UtcNow.DayOfWeek.ToString();

            context.Response.Write($"Hello from {GetType().Name} Handler :)");
            if (context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension == ".json")
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.Write($" \"day\" : \"{day}\" ");
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                context.Response.Write($"<div>It is {day}!</div><br/>");
            }
}
```

Also, it is working fine when handlers are registered in web.config file.
Am I missing something. Please help me in understanding why /handler/path.json is not being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a Web.config to the folder containing my JSON

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I assume you could add it to your root configuration as well

Comment: Getting following error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.json'

Comment: Check for the section in your web.config. Although, I suspect if it already exists, your issue is not the same as mine was.